# Dataset of judicial decisions in France

Tags: data-request, legal, france

I am looking for datasets containing [judicial decisions](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/judicial-decisions.php) in France.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find it here -  https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/
It is the official French government site for disseminating that type of information.